# Download data and then delete a google analytics view

Tags: google-analytics

I have a property with many views. Many of its views are not useful now but contain historical data. I want to remove now-useless views while preserving old data.

1. How do I backup/download this data if I need someday in future?
2. Can we move these views to another property. How?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can not download a Google analytics view.  Not all of it any way.  You can grab some of it using the Google Analytics API.  However I don't think this is what you are after.  There will be no way to reload the data into Google Analytics if you do.
2. You cant move a view from one web property to another.  Also if you delete the view you will loose the data forever.

My suggestion if you think you will need the data in the future leave it.

**Update / Note:** If you have a professional Google Analytics account you can also extract the data to big Query and store it there but I suspect it will cost you to do that.  However if you can afford a professional Google analytics account this probably wont be an issue for you.

Comment: Means there is no solution for this? 
How do companies across the world deal with such a situation for e.g. a startup idea pivots and there is no use of some views for the new idea?

Why don't they provide an option to move/download views data? Shouldn't they?

Comment: Leave them or delete them.   I inherited an account with 15 views in it (don't ask)  14 of them I ignore, they aren't even recording data anymore.  I  doesn't hurt anything having the views sitting there you aren't charged for them.